how to convert response to image with decoding?
I was using this code on python previously
with open(f"image.jpg", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(response.content)

and it was working fine, but now I changed lib for requests and the current script doesn't work
That is the new response.text example 
while old response.text looks like: 
tried this code to decode unicode:
with open(f"image.jpg", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(response.text.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode())

but the image is not correct, it does not display.
also tried:
ee = base64.encodebytes(rim.content[1:-1].decode('unicode_escape').replace('\\n','').replace('\n','').replace('\\r','').replace('\r','').encode()) 
and as result got: 
I did consider replacing all slashes and \n but still the result string is invalid. I believe there are some decode errors or my mistakes.
I use the same headers for content type and encoding in the request, so please, if it's possible, suggest solutions not related to the request itself.

Make a [mcve]..  We certainly can't decode an image of mojibake.

@MarkTolonen not that I disagree, but the fact that it's mojibake is a clue.  We can rule out it being base64 encoded for example.

@MarkRansom We don't know what the "new" response.text looks like.  The pastebin.com link is expired/removed.  I assume "old" response.text was the "working fine" one, but it is unclear.

@MarkTolonen did update, please take a look

It’s definitely not base64. But images of text are not helpful and we still don’t have a [mcve] (read and follow instructions in the link).  Show the request code.
